# PHP Optimized query call if nothing is selected

Tags: php

I am trying to make my coding more efficient and I am stuck at how to tell the query to display all the categories if nothing is selected.

I have 15 categories that the user can chose from, if none is selected, display all items. Rather than doing AND .. AND .. AND 15 times if nothing is selected, is there a smarter way for this?

This will work for one category selection:

```
$cate = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `posts` ORDER BY `id` ASC");                         
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($cate)){                             
    if($user_data['category'] === $row['id']) { 
        echo '<li>'.$row['name'].'</li>';                                       
    }                               
}   
$category_list = "AND `category_id` = '".$user_data['category']."'";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should generate your query dynamically

```
// General query
$query = "SELECT * FROM `posts`";

// If category selected
if ($user_data['category'] != 0) {
   $query .= " WHERE `category_id` = '".$user_data['category']."'";
}

// Order
$query .= " ORDER BY `id` ASC";

// Run query
$cate = mysql_query($query);
```

Or it  can be simplified using `Ternary Operator`:

```
// Generate query
$query = "SELECT * FROM `posts` ".($user_data['category'] != 0 ? "WHERE `category_id` = '".$user_data['category']."'" : "" )." ORDER BY `id` ASC";

// Run query
$cate = mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: I am doing it dynamically. If the user selects category "1" then show only items belonging to 1 and if 2 show only 2 and so on.. but if the user selects "0" (meaning "All"), how do I say show all items belonging to categories 1,2.....?

Comment: Just change the if-condition from `if (!empty($user_data['category']))` to `if ($user_data['category'] != 0)` (_see changes in the answer_)

Comment: So if `$user_data['category']` is zero (all), the `$query` would be `SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id ASC`, which will display all items. 

In every other case it will add `WHERE category_id = '".$user_data['category']."'"` to the `$query`, which will lead to displaying only items from a specific category.

Comment: wow, that was simple enough.. if =0, get " " in the query! else get the id.. brilliant!